# Calculate time differences between multiple set of data

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a data set in a mysql table which is related to a error log of an electronic divice.
i need to calculate the total down time.

```
time_stamp      error_type  error_status
1467820110           1           1
1467820120           2           1                  
1467820130           3           1
1467820140           3           0
1467820150           1           0
1467820160           2           0
1467820180           1           1
1467820185           1           0
1467820191           2           1
1467820300           2           0
1467820302           1           1
1467820404           3           1
1467820408           3           0
1467820409           1           0

error_status 1 = error occored
error_status 0 = error fixed

1st down time 1467820160 - 1467820110 = 50
2nd down time 1467820185 - 1467820180 = 5
3rd down time 1467820300 - 1467820191 = 109
4th down time 1467820409 - 1467820302 = 107

total down time = 50 + 5 + 109 + 107 = 271
```

How can i write a mySQL compatible SQL statement to achieve this.

Comment: what is the relation ship with error type and total value

Comment: @Kevin - do you can please post the create and inserts for the sample

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka just need the total regardless of the error type.

Comment: in that case please try below query

Comment: @BerndBuffen I do not have the access to such details. I've asked to create a report using this data format. The data is collected via a PLC

Comment: CREATE TABLE `db`.`errors` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time_stamp` INT NOT NULL,
  `error_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `error_status` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to calculate the number of cumulative errors that have occurred.  Then identify groups where the values are greater than 0.  This can be done by doing a cumulative count of the number of "0"s for the cumulative errors.

There is a challenge getting the final timestamp.  One trick is to get the next status 0 timestamp for the error.  This acts as an "end".

Finally, an aggregation get the information for each period:

```
select count(*) as num_errors, max(end_timestamp) - min(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := @grp + if(cume_errors = 0, 1, 0)) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (select t2.timestamp
                    from t t2
                    where t2.error_type = t.error_type and
                          t2.error_status = 0 and
                          t2.timestamp > t.timestamp
                    order by t2.timestamp asc
                    limit 1
                   ) as end_timestamp,
                   (@e := @e + if(error_status > 0, 1, -1)) as cume_errors
            from t cross join
                 (select @e := 0) params
            order by timestamp
           ) t cross join
           (select @grp := 0) params
      order by timestamp
     ) t
where error_status > 0
group by grp;
```

You can aggregate over this query to get the total period of downtime.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecee05/9) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use this you will get the total

```
SELECT sum(IF(error_status=1,time_stamp*-1,time_stamp)) as total FROM table;
```

----------example----

```
mysql> SELECT sum(IF(error_status=1,time_stamp*-1,time_stamp)) as total FROM hh;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|   315 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

mysql>  SELECT *,(IF(error_status=1,time_stamp*-1,time_stamp)) as total FROM hh;
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| time_stamp | error_type | error_status | total       |
+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1467820110 |          1 |            1 | -1467820110 |
| 1467820120 |          2 |            1 | -1467820120 |
| 1467820130 |          3 |            1 | -1467820130 |
| 1467820140 |          3 |            0 |  1467820140 |
| 1467820150 |          1 |            0 |  1467820150 |
| 1467820160 |          2 |            0 |  1467820160 |
| 1467820180 |          1 |            1 | -1467820180 |
| 1467820185 |          1 |            0 |  1467820185 |
| 1467820191 |          2 |            1 | -1467820191 |
| 1467820300 |          2 |            0 |  1467820300 |
| 1467820302 |          1 |            1 | -1467820302 |
| 1467820404 |          3 |            1 | -1467820404 |
| 1467820408 |          3 |            0 |  1467820408 |
| 1467820409 |          1 |            0 |  1467820409 |
```

Comment: Logic is correct when considering single error type. But different errors can be occurred in same time.

Comment: @Kevin : but still this will be correct because if you have error starting time it should have error fixed time and this will give time differnece

Comment: can you suggest any data set which can fail above logic

Comment: sorry for the late reply, my expected output is 271. This suggestion gives 315.

Comment: I want to calculate total down time. This gives the total time of each error.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecee05/16